# Prove that the area of their union is greater than $\frac{2}{9}S$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> A finite set of unit circles is given in a plane such that the area of their union $U$ is $S$. Prove that there exists a subset of mutually disjoint circles such that the area of their union is greater than $\frac{2}{9}S$.

What I am wondering is what if our finite set of circles is just like $10$ circles that are all in the same position in space. Then none of them is disjoint. How does there exist a subset of mutually disjoint circles with the desired property?

Or if that example was bad how do we know that there will always exist a subset of mutually disjoint circles? Maybe that will include only one circle?

Here is the official solution.
[image]

Comment: A student of mine found a different solution. Using strong induction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of the official solution:

Cover the plane in a tessellation of hexagons with inradius $2$. Then, put all of the hexagons on top of each other so all of the plane fits onto this one hexagon. This is kind of confusing, but basically, you have to visualize all of the circles becoming moved onto this one hexagon based on where they are in the tessellation. If they are at the top of one of the hexagons, they are now at the top of this hexagons; if they are at the bottom of one of the hexagons, they are now at the bottom of this hexagons; if they were partially in the top of one hexagon and in the bottom of another, part of them is now at the top of this hexagon and part of them is at the bottom of the hexagon.

Now, you have mushed an area of $S$ into an area of $8\sqrt 3$. This means that you must have some point that has $\frac{S}{8\sqrt 3}$ overlaps from circles that were originally from different hexagons. Understanding this takes some visualization, but basically, if $S > 8\sqrt 3$, then obviously, you will have some overlap from two different hexagons because you can mush more area into less area without overlapping. If you have $S > 16\sqrt 3$, then you have already covered the area two times, so now you need to overlap from three different hexagons in order to mush more area in. This pattern until it gets to how if you have $S$ area, you need overlap from $\frac{S}{8\sqrt 3}$ hexagons.

Once you have that figured out, now you need to visualize how if two circles overlap the same point on this hexagon and they are from different hexagons, then they are disjoint. This takes a lot of visualization and you need to account for the fact that the inradius of the hexagon is $2$ because if the inradius were smaller, this would not work. Try to draw or visualize different examples of tessellations and unit circles over those tessellations to see how this works. Make sure you draw unit circles over the border in order to deal with the border cases. Basically, the reason why unit circles can't overlap without being from different hexagons is because to overlap, they go at least the distance of the indiameter of $4$ and two unit circles can not overlap while overlapping points $4$ units apart because $4$ units is the sum of the diameter of two unit circles.

Now, we know that there is a point where there are overlaps from $\frac{S}{8\sqrt 3}$ different hexagons and that the circles from these hexagons are all disjoint. Thus, we have found $\frac{S}{8\sqrt 3}$ disjoint circles, meaning we have a set of mutually disjoint circles and since each circle has an area of $\pi$, the area of these circles altogether is $\pi\frac{S}{8\sqrt 3}=\frac{\pi}{8\sqrt 3}S>\frac 2 9 S$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the example you gave: There are $10$ congruent circles all completely overlapping with each other. Thus, the area of any one circle is the same as $S$, which is the area of the union of all of the circles, because the union of all of the circles is the same as any one of the circles. Thus, if one takes a subset containing just one circle, then that subset is mutually disjoint because there is only one circle and the area of the union of that set is $S$, which is clearly greater than $\frac 2 9 S$.

Just keep in mind that a set of one circle is mutually disjoint.

Comment: Hmm, so the claim seems to be that if none of the circles are disjoint with each other, then the area of one circle is at least $\frac{2}{9}S$.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to solve this? Should I take cases? The case where none of the circles are disjoint and the case where at least one is.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. The case when two disjoint circles exist is trivial. The other case is essentially: There are $9$ unit circles, such that each pair intersects, prove the area of the union is less than $\frac{9\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @TheKindCat I think you are misunderstanding the other case. You have to prove that if there is a set of unit circles that are all connected by overlaps somehow, there is a set of disjoint circles such that the area of those disjoint circles is more than $\frac 2 9$ of the whole set. Each pair of circles does not need to be touching, but each pair of circles needs to be connected through overlapping circles.

Comment: @NobleMushtak And the first case as well since we don't necessarily have $9$ circles.

Comment: @NobleMushtak if all of the circles are touching each other you can only pick one of them. All of them have are $\pi$ so it doesn't matter which one you pick.

Comment: If we have exactly two disjoint circles, can't we just make $S$ as large as we want by keeping the other circles not disjoint? Then how is it possible to get greater than $\frac{2}{9}S$?

Comment: @TheKindCat Oh...I misunderstood what you said, but what you said makes sense now. Can you explain how the case where there are disjoint circles is trivial, though?

Comment: If you have two circles then you can pick them, they have an area of $2\pi$.This works as long as $S$ is not $9\pi$. But if $S$ is $9\pi$ then there must be $3$ disjoint circles(this is a little tricky, but not too hard), in which case you are also done.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Not necessarily, because by keeping all of the other circles not disjoint and making sure that each pair of circles has some overlap, you are limiting the amount of area you can make.

Comment: @TheKindCat What if $S$ is more than $9\pi$?

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought we had $9$ circles, I'm so dumb.

Comment: This isn't true if we change circle with convex set of area $\pi$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak I have the official solution, so if I put it in the question can you post an easier to understand explanation of it?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Yes, I think I would be able to simplify a more complicated explanation because I've done that a lot of times before.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Do you see it?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still trying to figure out how it works. This might take a while, but I'll have an answer eventually; sorry for the delay.

Comment: @NobleMushtak They say there exists a unique mapping, but is the mapping taking it to the same spot it was on $x$ to $\gamma$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Yes, that is what they are doing. What I was confused about, however, is how they assumed that points were overlapped by disjoint circles, but I understand now. I'm writing another answer about this right now.